# Return to Editor not working on Kile

Tags: kile

Supposedly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is supposed to return from Okular to Kile, but when I press it nothing happens, even though I see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is indeed listed as the shortcut for this command.

I am working with Kile 2.9.60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that what I thought ''Return to Editor'' does, is done by the ''Focus Editor View'' command, whose default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and works well!
That is, Focus Editor View will get the cursor back into the editor.

[image]